# Wordpress inserting rewrite_rules option more than once

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

I'm trying to optimize a slow wordpress site. I use a plugin called Query Monitor to find something abnormal.

I can see that the rewrite_rules option  is reinserted every page (more than 50000 characters).

Here is the stacktrace :

```
add_option()

-
update_option()
 wp-includes/option.php:301
WP_Rewrite->wp_rewrite_rules()
 wp-includes/class-wp-rewrite.php:1452
WP_Rewrite->flush_rules()
 wp-includes/class-wp-rewrite.php:1774
do_action('wp_loaded')
 wp-includes/plugin.php:525
```

These files seems like core wordpress files.

I'm not sure if this is the normal behaviour ? I think not because I see no good reason.

Have you seen this before ?

Comment: I'm not seeing anything inserted more than once in the output you've shared...

Comment: No, the option is deleted before (flush), so I'll always have one line. I'm just wondering why they execute a long query every page. It's not like my permalinks will change every minutes.